# Variation of Parameters constraint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello there: I'm currently taking a freshman class on Differential Equations and want to know more about how it works.
I understand that you are trying to find two linear independent particular solutions that are functions of the independent variable. But if you are looking for two equations $u_1(t)$ and $u_2(t)$, why are you allowed to impose the condition:

$y_1(t)u'_1(t) + y_2(t)u'_2(t) = 0$

Is this an just a condition you impose on the function so that it is easier to find the solution. Is this the only solution? Are there other functions of $t$ that serve as a particular solution if you impose a different condition?

I watched Herbert Gross' video on variation of parameters: https://youtu.be/IYKULUq6YPQ?t=414 where he says that you are allowed one degree of freedom when imposing a constraint on the set of functions. What does he mean by that? Any insight/explanations would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: $u_1$ and $u_2$ are purely random. We can choose them to be whatever we want. So we look for such $u_1$ and $u_2$ that satisfies $y_1(t)u'_1(t) + y_2(t)u'_2(t) = 0$. In your terms, it is just a condition we impose in order to make calculations easier.